# spring/application.rb:161 undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, nomethoderror

I am using ruby 2.5 and rails 5.0.1 for my application. when i try to run console or generate controller or migration it gives me this error:

`Running via Spring preloader in process 6473
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
/home/abwahed/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in`fork': undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There was an active discussion about this issue few days back [here](https://github.com/rails/spring/pull/551) in spring gems repo. The underlying ruby gem `binding_of_caller` was creating the issue with ruby 2.5.0. The issue is marked as closed with a pr now here in [binding_of_caller_repo](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/pull/69). So, I think you can simply do a `bundle update` or `bundle update binding_of_caller` to fix it. You can also try downgrading ruby to `2.4.3` if that doesn't worked. Hope this helps.